# getTransactionCount return different response

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, nonce

geth version 1.8.27

The pending nonce is 8 at first, then I send a transaction and use `eth.getTransactionCount` to get the next pending nonce.

```js
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdc34f16b577032c49dddf0b0c44455fc29dbcf3e","pending")
8
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdc34f16b577032c49dddf0b0c44455fc29dbcf3e","pending")
8
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdc34f16b577032c49dddf0b0c44455fc29dbcf3e","pending")
8
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdc34f16b577032c49dddf0b0c44455fc29dbcf3e","pending")
9
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdc34f16b577032c49dddf0b0c44455fc29dbcf3e","pending")
8
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdc34f16b577032c49dddf0b0c44455fc29dbcf3e","pending")
9
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdc34f16b577032c49dddf0b0c44455fc29dbcf3e","pending")
9
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdc34f16b577032c49dddf0b0c44455fc29dbcf3e","pending")
9
> eth.getTransactionCount("0xdc34f16b577032c49dddf0b0c44455fc29dbcf3e","pending")
9
```

I have two questions:
1. I use `txpool.content.pending` and see there's a tx in the pending list(nonce=8). But `eth.getTransactionCount` still return 8 and after a while, it return 9.

2. Why `eth.getTransactionCount` still return a 8 when it returned 9 last time? 
   (shown in the log above)

Answer (score 2):

1. Before you perform a transaction there is a total of 8 transactions. When you do another transaction then there is total 9 transaction(8 Confirmed & 1 Pending). Therefore `eth.getTransactionCount` returns 9.
2. When a transaction is confirmed on the blockchain, it will take some times to reflect on the block. At this time transaction is not in pending state and also not added to block. That's why for a moment `eth.getTransactionCount` returns 8.

Comment: That's a bug of `eth.getTransactionCount`

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a nature of ethereum blockchain and that is how it works.